# JavaScript - 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript

I can't solve this (learning JS), there are other threads but none helped me.

According to '[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)':

Adding a Node, is simple:

```
// Create a new paragraph element, and append it to the end of the document body
var p = document.createElement("p");
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

However, when i do something like that, i get:

**"... parameter 1 is not of type Node"**

JS code:

```
(function () {

    var myNode = document.querySelector('#shiny-pics .pixgrid ul');       
    myNode.addEventListener("click", function(e) {        
        if (e.target.tagName === 'IMG') {         
            var myOverlay = document.createElement('div');
            myOverlay.id = 'overlay';
            document.body.appendChild('myOverlay');
            /*console.log(typeof(myOverlay));*/
            /*console.log(myOverlay.prototype.toString());*/
        }
    
    }, false); //image is clicked       
})();
```

I've also tried to see the type of  my var 'myOverlay' (with **typeof**) , but it just says **object**.

And also with: ['Object.prototype.toString'](https://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#types), but I only see the first error that says that the object is not of type node. See my commented code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending (or attempting to append) the string `'myOverlay'` and not the node you created. Just as in the first sample of code you didn't write

```
  document.body.appendChild('p');
```

you should write

```
    document.body.appendChild(myOverlay);
```

Comment: so embarrasing, long day coding. Thanks!